# ThinkPad S440 wifi and unexpected system halt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, thinkpad

Just a few days ago I installed new wifi driver and everything seemed to work fine on Lenovo ThinkPad S440. The problem is that the system crashes unexpectedly. [This is a pastebin of dmesg (/var/log/syslog)](http://pastebin.com/qhqLFzny) output so you could see what's happening. When the system crashes, X and all other programs crash. I can't even switch to tty and restart X. Can't be reproduced. Don't know how to show you the output I see on the screen.

**Update**
I used a kernel boot flag `acpi_os=Windows noapic` on my Ubuntu 12.04 on Lenovo ThinkPad S440 because I suppose that if they've build it with Windows8+ in mind, it could help somehow, but I'm not sure.

**Update 2**
Here is a screenshot of what happens unexpectedly. Can't reproduce it. Didn't test it with Windows and wouldn't like to do this. I need linux for work.

[image]

Comment: Is the system totally stable in Windows? (Can you rule out hardware?)

Comment: No, didn't test it with Windows. See please Update 2.

Comment: Definitely a kernel panic. I'd wager the wireless driver is killing you. It could also be a hardware fault. You could try booting on older kernels, there may be glimmer of hope there. Else, I'd first try a different wireless card.

Comment: [here is](http://askubuntu.com/questions/411755/thinkpad-s440-wifi-and-unexpected-system-halt/413311?iemail=1&noredirect=1#413311) a main thread